# UIMA integrate DLL

Tags: dll, uima

How can UIMA integrate DLLs?I want to make a system ,it can integrate some components in the UIMA !
Then how can I do it?

Comment: Dynamically Linked Libraries, right? Could you give an example?

Comment: Yes!For example,I write a dll,it can print "Hello world",I integrate it into the UIMA architecture,then in the UIMA architecture,it can also print "Hello world"!How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could write a [C++ UIMA](http://uima.apache.org/doc-uimacpp-huh.html) Annotator, and call your DLL from it. Would that work? UIMA has an exmaple in `examples/src/ExampleApplication.cpp`, or you could call your C++ Annotator from a Java UIMA pipeline.